# If "var date = data[0][0]" returns values from column A how do I get values column C?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a Google Script to pull Google Form data from Sheets to make an event in Google Calendar. The form populates two columns of data (timestamp and a number). I use a formula in column C to generate a title from the data in column B. No matter what I try I can only get the data in column B to show up in the calendar.

```
// function to retrieve data from Sheet and add to Calendar
function simpleSheetsToCalendar() {

  // get spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // get the data from Google Sheet
  var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,3).getValues();

  //  create variables
  var date = data[0][0];
  var title = data[0][3];

  // get calendar
  var masterCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('uknowme@gmail.com');

  // add to calendar
  masterCal.createAllDayEvent(title,date);  

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change this `var title = data[0][3];` to this `var title = data[0][2];` Columns start at one. Array indices start at zero.  So data[0][2] is actually column 3 data.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you Cooper. I could have sworn I tried all variations I could think of but apparently I hadn't. I tried upvoting your answer but I don't have enough points. Thanks again!

Comment: You can check it off.  There should be a check mark on the left.  Glad it work for you.